# Variation partition analysis: morphology-climate correlation, controlling for geography

Tags: r, partitioning, vegan

I'm working with three datasets with informations about individuals: morphological data, climatic data of the individual sampling site and geographical data.

My objective is to assess whether morphology is affected by climate, controlling for the effect of geography.

I initially used partial Mantel test, however, there is a list of papers that discourage from using it. They rather suggest to use Variation Partition analyses.

Here I'm using varpart function in "vegan" package in R.

I run a k-means analysis on the morphological data and extracted the component explaining most variance: `morpho_data`

I run a PCA on climate data and extracted the component explaining most variance: `climate_data`

I used PCNM to convert original geographical distances between individuals: `geo_PCNM`

Then I run the varpart function:

```
varpart(morpho_data,climate_data, geo_PCNM)
```

Do you think my analyses and reasoning is correct?